# how to display group messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please help me, I'm new in react. I'm rendering values from nested object. Each object has title and message property. Titles can be same. I want display messages under title. If title same as in previos object do not display it , only once. But in my case it displays after each message.

my object:

```
arrayOfMessages=[
  {
    title: 'cars',
    message: 'toyota'
  },
  {
    title: 'cars',
    message: 'ford'
  },
  {
    title: 'cars',
    message: 'bmw'
  },
  {
    title: 'bikes',
    message: 'suzuki'
  },
  {
    title: 'bikes',
    message: 'bmw'
  },
]
```

expected output:

```
   title
     message
     message
     message

   title2
     message
     message
```

in my case:

```
   title
     message
   title
     message
   title
     message

   title2
     message
   title2
     message

<div>
          {arrayOfMessages.map((item, idx) => {
            const {
              message,
              title
            } = item
            return (
              <div key={idx} className="message-content">
                <p>{title}</p>
                <p>{message}</p>
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
```

Comment: can you share your object structure?

Comment: You need to group your `arrayOfMessages` based on title (or perhaps some other identifier). There are libraries such as `lodash` that make this easy for you but there are also code snippets available such as https://gist.github.com/ramsunvtech/102ac0267d33c2cc1ccdf9158d0f7fca

Comment: @PrasannaBrabourame added

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
 render(){
   //title watcher
   let watcher = {};
   return   <div>
          {arrayOfMessages.map((item, idx) => {
            const {
              message,
              title
            } = item
             if(!watcher[title]){ 
                //update watcher with title
                //if watcher does not contain your title return title and message
                watcher[title]=title;
               return (
              <div key={idx} className="message-content">
                <p>{title}</p>
                <p>{message}</p>
              </div>
               )
             } else {
               //if watcher found with title return your message
                <div key={idx} className="message-content">
                <p>{message}</p>
              </div>
             }



          })}
        </div>

 }
```

Comment: did you get it @Yerlan Yeszhanov

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to group items of `arrayOfMessages` by the `title` field, to achieve the required rendering result by using the native `.reduce()` method:

```js
const arrayOfMessages=[
  {
    title: 'cars',
    message: 'toyota'
  },
  {
    title: 'cars',
    message: 'ford'
  },
  {
    title: 'cars',
    message: 'bmw'
  },
  {
    title: 'bikes',
    message: 'suzuki'
  },
  {
    title: 'bikes',
    message: 'bmw'
  },
];

/* Use reduce() to group items of arrayOfMessages by title */
const groupedMessages = arrayOfMessages.reduce((groups, item) => {
  
  /* Find group for the title of current item */
  const group = groups.find(group => group.title === item.title);
  
  /* If matching group found, add message of item to it's messages array */
  if(group) {
    group.messages.push(item.message);
  }
  /* Otherwise, add a new group for this title */
  else {
    groups.push({ title : item.title, messages : [] });
  }

  return groups;
  
}, [])

console.log(groupedMessages);
```

Using the code above, you could then revise your `render()` method to render the `title` once for each item category:

```
<div>
    { groupedMessages.map((group, idx0) => (<div key={idx0} className="message-content">
        <h2>{ group.title }</h2>
        { group.messages.map((message, idx1) => (<p key={idx1}>{message}</p>)) }        
        </div>))
    }
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your object is not well structured, should be like this:

```
arrayOfMessages=[
  {
    title:"cars",
    description:["toyota","ford","bmw"]
  },
  {
    title:"bike",
    description:["suzuki","bmw"]
  }
]
```

then you can implement your code like this :

```
{
  arrayOfMessages.map((message, idx) => {
    const { description, title } = message
    return (
      <div key={idx} className="message-content">
        <p>{title}</p>
        {description.map((desc, index) => (
          <p key={index}>desc</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make up your data first.

```
...
let renderMessages = {}
arrayOfMessages.forEach(message => {
  if (!renderMessages[message.title]) {
    renderMessages[message.title] = {
      title: message.title,
      messages: [message.message]
    }
  } else {
    renderMessages[message.title].messages.push(message.message)
  }
})

return (
  <div>
    {Object.keys(renderMessages).map(key => {
      let msg = renderMessages[key]
      return <div key={key} className="message-content">
        <p>{msg.title}</p>
        {msg.messages.map(content => <p key={content}>{content}</p>)} 
      </div>
    })}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group the messages based on the `title` using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Then loop through the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the merged object to get the desired format

```js
const arrayOfMessages=[{title:'cars',message:'toyota'},{title:'cars',message:'ford'},{title:'cars',message:'bmw'},{title:'bikes',message:'suzuki'},{title:'bikes',message:'bmw'},]

const grouped = arrayOfMessages.reduce((acc, { title, message }) => {
  acc[title] = acc[title] || [];
  acc[title].push(message);
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(grouped)
```

Here's a live demo:

```js
class Sample extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const arrayOfMessages = [{ title: 'cars', message: 'toyota' }, { title: 'cars', message: 'ford' }, { title: 'cars', message: 'bmw' }, { title: 'bikes', message: 'suzuki' }, { title: 'bikes', message: 'bmw' },]

    const grouped = arrayOfMessages.reduce((acc, { title, message }) => {
      acc[title] = acc[title] || [];
      acc[title].push(message);
      return acc;
    }, {})

    return (
      <div>
        {
          Object.entries(grouped).map(([title, messages], i1) => (
            <div key={i1}>
              <h1>{title}</h1>
              { messages.map((message, i2) => (<p key={i2}>{message}</p>)) }
            </div>)
          )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Sample />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```